# Azure REST API throws "WAF Policy does not have any valid Primary Rule Set attached to it." error

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door, azure-rest-api, web-application-firewall

The Azure REST API that I'm trying to call to update my WAF policy is throwing an error saying the policy doesn't have any valid primary rule set attached to it. This is the API I'm trying to hit - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/web-application-firewall-policies/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP

I have set up AFD and configured WAF to it. I'm also able to create a WAF policy through portal. I'm unsure if I've missed some proper configs as I've set up everything purely for testing purpose. This is essentially what I followed to set up AFD - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

By using the access token, I created **Web Application Firewall Policies**:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/ruk/providers/Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/Policy1?api-version=2023-02-01

{
  "location": "WestUs",
  "properties": {
    "policySettings": {
      "logScrubbing": {
        "state": "Enabled",
        "scrubbingRules": [
          {
            "state": "Enabled",
            "matchVariable": "RequestArgNames",
            "selectorMatchOperator": "Equals",
            "selector": "test"
          },
          {
            "state": "Enabled",
            "matchVariable": "RequestIPAddress",
            "selectorMatchOperator": "EqualsAny"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "managedRules": {
      "managedRuleSets": [
        {
          "ruleSetType": "OWASP",
          "ruleSetVersion": "3.2",
          "ruleGroupOverrides": [
            {
              "ruleGroupName": "REQUEST-931-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RFI",
              "rules": [
                {
                  "ruleId": "931120",
                  "state": "Enabled",
                  "action": "Log"
                },
                {
                  "ruleId": "931130",
                  "state": "Disabled",
                  "action": "AnomalyScoring"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "exclusions": [
        {
          "matchVariable": "RequestArgNames",
          "selectorMatchOperator": "StartsWith",
          "selector": "hello",
          "exclusionManagedRuleSets": [
            {
              "ruleSetType": "OWASP",
              "ruleSetVersion": "3.2",
              "ruleGroups": [
                {
                  "ruleGroupName": "REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI",
                  "rules": [
                    {
                      "ruleId": "930120"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "ruleGroupName": "REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "matchVariable": "RequestArgNames",
          "selectorMatchOperator": "EndsWith",
          "selector": "hello",
          "exclusionManagedRuleSets": [
            {
              "ruleSetType": "OWASP",
              "ruleSetVersion": "3.1",
              "ruleGroups": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "matchVariable": "RequestArgNames",
          "selectorMatchOperator": "StartsWith",
          "selector": "test"
        },
        {
          "matchVariable": "RequestArgValues",
          "selectorMatchOperator": "StartsWith",
          "selector": "test"
        }
      ]
    },
    "customRules": [
      {
        "name": "Rule1",
        "priority": 1,
        "ruleType": "MatchRule",
        "action": "Block",
        "matchConditions": [
          {
            "matchVariables": [
              {
                "variableName": "RemoteAddr",
                "selector": null
              }
            ],
            "operator": "IPMatch",
            "matchValues": [
              "192.168.1.0/24",
              "10.0.0.0/24"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Rule2",
        "priority": 2,
        "ruleType": "MatchRule",
        "matchConditions": [
          {
            "matchVariables": [
              {
                "variableName": "RemoteAddr",
                "selector": null
              }
            ],
            "operator": "IPMatch",
            "matchValues": [
              "192.168.1.0/24"
            ]
          },
          {
            "matchVariables": [
              {
                "variableName": "RequestHeaders",
                "selector": "UserAgent"
              }
            ],
            "operator": "Contains",
            "matchValues": [
              "Windows"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "action": "Block"
      },
      {
        "name": "RateLimitRule3",
        "priority": 3,
        "rateLimitDuration": "OneMin",
        "rateLimitThreshold": 10,
        "ruleType": "RateLimitRule",
        "matchConditions": [
          {
            "matchVariables": [
              {
                "variableName": "RemoteAddr",
                "selector": null
              }
            ],
            "operator": "IPMatch",
            "negationConditon": true,
            "matchValues": [
              "192.168.1.0/24",
              "10.0.0.0/24"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "groupByUserSession": [
          {
            "groupByVariables": [
              {
                "variableName": "ClientAddr"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "action": "Block"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

The **WAF policy** created in the resource group:

[image]

Now I tried to update the WAF policy, **updating the custom rule name**:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/ruk/providers/Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/Policy1?api-version=2023-02-01


"customRules": [
{
"name": "RuleRuk",
"priority": 1,
"ruleType": "MatchRule",
"action": "Block",
"matchConditions": [
{
"matchVariables": [
{
"variableName": "RemoteAddr",
"selector": null
}
],
```

[image]

The **custom rule name updated successfully** like below:

[image]

**Note** that: You have to pass resource group name in which the WAF policy is present to update the policy.